# Nested integral question with integral as upper bound of integration. (Recursive Integral? Nested Integral?) In form: $\int_0^I f(x) dx = I$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

NOTE: Even though this question has been marked "Answered" there are still some unanswered questions I would still appreciate answers for. Thank you!

**Disclaimer:** I'm not sure about the proper term for this type of problem, since I couldn't find it anywhere online except for this youtube video*, in which it is called a nested integral. However, once I looked the term up here to see if the question had been asked before, completely different things popped up, so I apologize for any confusion that may have been created.
*https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnFCncV-288&t=1s

When you compute the integral $\int_0^I 2x dx = I$, you get two solutions: 1 and 0. I have a few questions here:

1. Is this a sort of definite integral? (If not, is there a proper term for this?) If so, how can it equal two things at once?
2. Are both answers correct? If so, which answer would be more valid, if either?
3. When this is extended to $\int_0^I 4x^3 dx = I$ (And past. i.e $\int_0^I 17x^{16} dx = I$), you start to get complex solutions. Are these valid answers? If so, how do you take an integral with a complex number as a bound of integration? (is there an intuitive graphical representation of this that could help me understand?)
4. Given $\int_0^I f(x) dx = I$, and $F(I)-I-F(0)=0$, are there functions $f(x)$ that have infinitely many solutions*? Are there equations with an infinite amount of real solutions and a finite number of complex? <strike>Functions with a finite number of real and an infinite number of complex?</strike>$^{I have figured out a function that fits these criteria.}$ Are there functions with zero solutions of both, or functions that only have complex solutions? (I would also be interested in more functions with purely real solutions** outside of trivial ones like, $2x dx$, and $3x^2 dx$. Anything in the form $\int_0^I nx dx = I$, $n \in \Bbb R$, $n \neq 0$, is trivial and the solution is given by $I = \frac{2}{n}$, $0$.)

*Outside of $\int_0^I 1dx = I$, which is valid for everything.

**Another function I have found is $\int_0^I \ln (x)dx = I$, which gives the result $e^2$. In addition, if you take $\int_0^I \ln (nx) dx = I$, you get a solution in the form $\frac {e^2}{n}$ when $n \neq 0, e$. If $n = e^c$, where $c \in \Bbb N$, you get an answer in the form $\frac {e^2}{e^c}$, or $\frac {1}{e^{c-2}}$. If $n=e^{-c}$, $c \geq 1$, the rule appears to be $I = e^{c+2}$. The rule for when $c \lt 1$ is more complex, and I don't believe I fully understand it. If $c$ is in the form $\frac {1}{r}$, where $r \in \Bbb Z$, the solution is $e^{\frac {2r-1}{r}}$, and when in the form $\frac {k}{r}$, with $k \in \Bbb Z$ and $k \neq 1$, as long as it doesn't reduce into the previous form $\frac {1}{r_1}$, the solution is instead given by $e^{\frac {2r+k}{r}}$. I would like help understanding why this is. In the case $n^{-c}$, $c \in \Bbb Z$, the rule is simply $ce^2$. For the cases where $c$ is a fraction, the rule is again different. I will update this soon once I have more time.

Representation of what one of these integrals look like for anyone who might be confused: $$\int_0^{\int_0^{\int_0^I f(x) dx} f(x) dx} f(x) dx = I$$

Some things I've noticed: I am fairly sure you can use some sort of trigonometry to find something with infinite solutions, as it's periodic, but my math is not advanced enough to prove anything here. All I know is that if you want $n$ number of solutions it is very easy to generate it by taking $\int_0^I nx^{n-1} dx = I$ when $n \in \Bbb N$.

Also, bonus question: Is there a way to write this as an infinite series, or continued fraction, or something in that vein?

<strike>Bonus bonus question I thought of just as I was about to post this: What would the solution be to $\int_0^I \frac 1x dx = I$? Is there a solution?</strike>

- Note for this question: When plugged into Symbolab, it says that this integral "diverges." What does it mean in this context? Is it accurate?

Bonus bonus bonus question: Can every $f(x)$ that does not have an undefined section (as in $\int_0^I \frac 1x dx = I$) be solved for a numerical value? If not, why? Same for if so.

- Note for this question: For example, would this be solvable if, say, $f(x)$ was $e^{-x^2}$, as in the Gaussian Integral? Would the integral only be solvable if it had an elementary integral?

I couldn't find any tags I thought matched this well enough, so I just went with improper-integrals, integration, and calculus.

Thank you! I would appreciate answers to any of these questions, but I'll only mark the question "answered" if all of my main questions have been answered.

Note: I have slightly edited this to make some aspects of the question clearer and more precise.

Note 2: I have again edited this to update with some new findings and interesting tidbits, as well as slightly clarify some things.

Note 3: Same as Note 2.

Comment: In general, an equation $F(I)=G(I)$ can have more than one solution $I$.  This equation, $I = \int_0^I 2x\;dx$, is actually the equation $I^2=I$, and has $2$ solutions.  Or maybe it has $3$ solutions including $I=+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you! Would that mean that the integral is definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a function $f$ that is continuous on an interval $J$ and $a\in J$. Then, for every $x$ in $J$, the **definite integral**

$$A(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\; dt$$

exists in $\mathbb R$ (as the limit of Riemann Sums). This defines a function $A$ from $J$ into $\mathbb R$. The problem in the linked video is to find the *fixed points* $I$ of the function $A$, that is the numbers $I$ satisfying $A(I)=I$.

In the case where $f$ has an elementary antiderivative, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus implies that the equation **written** using an integral can be written as a "classic equation". In the given example where $f(x)=2x$ and $a=0$, we have

$$
\int^I_0 2x\; dx = I \iff I^2 = I
$$

To answer your questions,

> 1. Is this a sort of definite integral? (If not, is there a proper term for this?) If so, how can it equal two things at once?

The quantity $\int_0^I 2x\; dx$ is a definite integral. Note that definite integrals are just a way of expressing numbers (for example, $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(x)\; dx$ is just another way of writing $0$). Numbers can be expressed in a lot of ways.

> 2. Are both answers correct? If so, which answer would be more valid, if either?

$\int_0^I f(x)\; dx = I$ is an **equation**. It can have $0$, $1$, finitely or infinitely many solutions. None of them is more valid (except if more conditions are given, such as we are looking for positive solutions.)

> 3. When this is extended to $\int_0^I 4x^3 dx = I$ (And past. i.e $\int_0^I 17x^{16} dx = I$), you start to get complex solutions. Are these valid answers? If so, how do you take an integral with a complex number as a bound of integration? (is there an intuitive graphical representation of this that could help me understand?)

That should probably be an independent question, as it is a vast subject. The construction of definite integrals can be extended to line segments $[a,b]$ where $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers. Remember that complex numbers are points in the plane, so line segment between them is well-defined. Alternatively, you can look at **line integrals**.

> 4. Given $\int_0^I f(x) dx = I$, and $F(I)-I-F(0)=0$, are there functions $f(x)$ that have infinitely many solutions*?

I will answer the first part only. You can always choose an antiderivative whose value at $0$ is $0$ (if defined at $0$), so the equation becomes $F(I)=I$, and you are looking for a function $F$ with infinitely many fixed points. For example, you can consider $F(x)=x+\sin(x)$ (so $f(x)=1+\cos(x)$). So your intuition about trigonometric functions was right!

> Bonus bonus bonus question: Can every $f(x)$ that does not have an undefined section (as in $\int_0^I \frac 1x dx = I$) be solved for a numerical value? If not, why? Same for if so.

Not every equation has solutions that can be expressed using elementary functions. As for numerical approximations, if $f$ is continuous, then $A$ is differentiable, so you can use standard techniques (Intermediate Value Theorem or Newton's Method for the solutions of $A(I)-I=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments on 1,2, and the first part of 4. It looks like my math isn't quite advanced enough for 3 yet (I'll consider asking it as an independent question after I make sure it hasn't been asked before), so I suppose I'll work on that. As for 4, thank you for confirming my intuition. I have no clue how I missed that, it looks so obvious in hindsight. Since the main part of all my questions has been answered, I want to declare the post Answered, but will other people still be able to answer the other questions on #4 after your post is marked as the answer? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, people can answer even if one answer has already been accepted. But you can only accept one answer (there are possibilities to change the accepted answer, but I forgot how). You don't have to accept an answer quickly.